# Error when importing data source from web using GDAL/OGR in GRASS 7.4.1

Tags: gdal, grass-gis

I am running the latest bundle of OSGeo4W with GRASS 7.4.1

I am following the tutorial in the following URL:
[Analysing the ECA&D climatic data](https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/02_grass-gis_ecad_analysis/), where I am trying to import data from web using this code:

`INFILE="/vsizip/vsicurl/https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip"`

However, I get the error:

```
INFILE is not recognizable as an internal or external command, a program or an executable file
```

I am not sure this error is because of using wrong syntax, or because GDAL/OGR isn´t installed/activated properly

If you need more information please comment bellow and I will gladly provide it

Comment: Did you run also the preceding commands? Your error seems like you'd written the command to the normal windows shell instead of GRASS shell.

Comment: Yes, I ran all the preceding commands. I typed the command in the console of the GRASS GUI, not outside the program. Have you tried running it on your device?

Comment: I guess that because you are on Windows you need to use Windows syntax. Try with `SET INFILE=...` and then `v.import input=%INFILE% output=country_boundaries`. I don't have GRASS available so I can't test myself.

Comment: Using the SET command I was able to load the data from external web. However, I am unable to run the v.import command. Is this because I need to use a Widnows specific syntax? If so, where can I find instructions for this.

Comment: Let's hope that some GRASS specialist takes your question. Otherwise write to https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/grass-user. The list seems to be active. May be that GRASS developers do not prefer Windows, though.

Comment: Indeed, the usage of the INFILE variable is shell specific (with Msys that also works on Windows!). However, I'll consider to adapt that v.import line.

Comment: Fixed, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated that example to not use the (convenient) variable definition:

```
v.import input="/vsizip/vsicurl/https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip" output=country_boundaries
```

Please check again here:

https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/02_grass-gis_ecad_analysis/#country-admin-borders

Comment: This works great. Thank you Markus. I have been following your courses to learn GRASS